# How do I use existing functions (math) from the existing libraries in a new package?

Tags: libraries, modelica

I'm developing a new package with some simple functions. Now it turns out I could use functions in the already existing "math-vectors" library; specifically "interpolate" and "reverse". How to I use these in my new package? It's clearly not sufficient to write `y:=reverse(...)` because then I get the error message `function reverse not found in scope myTestModel`. What syntax applies here?

Comment: Either use full name Modelica.Math.Vectors.reverse or import the function. https://mbe.modelica.university/components/packages/importing/

Comment: OK, thanks Priyanka... I will try this.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments by @Priyanka :

```
y:=Modelica.Math.Vectors.reverse(...);
```

or (see also https://mbe.modelica.university/components/packages/importing/ ):

```
import Modelica.Math.Vectors.reverse; // At the start of your function/model.
...
y:=reverse(...);
```

For import you can choose from:

```
import Modelica.Math.Vectors.reverse; // Just this one
import Modelica.Math.Vectors.{reverse,sort}; // More than one.
```

And additionally there is:

```
import Modelica.Math.Vectors.*; // All - be careful
import reverse=Modelica.Math.Vectors.sort; // Alias, DON'T!
```